# Special cases for table.remove

Tags: lua, lua-table

[The reference manual](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-table.remove) of `table.remove` says:

> #### `table.remove (list [, pos])`
>
> Removes from `list` the element at position `pos`, returning the value of the removed element. When `pos` is an integer between `1` and `#list`, it shifts down the elements `list[pos+1]`, `list[pos+2]`, ···, `list[#list]` and erases element `list[#list]`; The index `pos` can also be `0` when `#list` is `0`, or `#list + 1`; in those cases, the function erases the element `list[pos]`.

The last two special cases where `pos` is `0` or `#list + 1` interests me.

---

Example code of `pos` being `0`:

```
local t1 = {[0] = 'foo'}
table.remove(t1, 0)
```

In this case, the element `t1[0]` is removed.

---

Example code of `pos` being `#list + 1`:

```
local t2 = {'foo', 'bar', 'baz'}
table.remove(t2, #t2 + 1)
```

In this case, nothing is changed, except that the statement won't raise error.

---

Is my understanding correct? When are theses two special cases useful in practice?

I also noted that the two cases are added since Lua 5.2

Comment: @Babyy length of `t2`

Comment: In many situations `table.remove(t, 1)` and `table.remove(t, #t)` should better be valid even if `#t == 0`, that's why those special cases were introduced.

Comment: Seems to be added in Lua 5.2.2 between rc2 and rc3: http://lua.2524044.n2.nabble.com/ANN-Lua-5-2-2-rc3-now-available-td7646986.html

Answer (score 1):

The last two special cases help set and define boundaries in the *5.2 version*.  There are other changes to `table.remove` that are relevant to why this is done.  Take a look!

```
-- Lua 5.1 version
t = {'foo', 'bar' , 'baz'}

local v = table.remove(t, 1)
print(v) 
>>nil
table.remove(t, 7)
-- no crash or error message
```

---

```
-- Lua 5.2 version
t = {'foo', 'bar' , 'baz'}

local v = table.remove(t, 1)
print(v) 
>>foo
table.remove(t, 7)
>>stdin:1 bad argument #1 to 'remove' (position out of bounds)
```

When the user calls `table.remove` in *5.2*, the value is removed from the table ***and is returned***.  In *5.1*, the value is only removed. 
 Additionally in the *5.2 version* an error message is generated when the user tries to remove an element from a position that is out of bounds.

What does this have to do with the special cases?  Well for one if they didn't include

> The index `pos` can also be `0` when `#list` is `0`

to the argument, then when using `table.remove(t)` on an empty table it would crash.  Keep in mind that tables are heterogeneous and in a lot of cases are used both as an array and hash map at the same time!  Sometimes it is desired to get rid of the array portion while retaining the hash map.  To that end,

```
while table.remove(t) do end  -- ends when the t runs out of elements at t[0]
```

---

There is a caveat though!  If `#list > 0` when using `table.remove(list, 0)` it will crash!  The `#list` has to be equal to `0`.

```
-- Lua 5.2 version
t = {'foo', 'bar' , 'baz'}

table.remove(t, 0) -- #t is 3
>>stdin:1 bad argument #1 to 'remove' (position out of bounds)
table.remove(t)    -- baz
table.remove(t)    -- bar
table.remove(t)    -- foo
-- #t is now 0
table.remove(t, 0) -- nil
-- nothing happens
```

---

The last special case `#list + 1` is just to make the syntax cleaner when trimming a list.  Instead of having to do a `for` loop to erase elements to `pos` you can just,

```
-- 7 is just a random number I picked
while table.remove(t, 7) do end  -- this will end when the t[7] = nil (aka #t + 1)
```

---

Hopefully this was helpful!

Answer (score 0):

Tables work by matching keys and values. By default, the keys start from 1 and go to #list. All undefined keys have the value of nil.

```
t = {}
print(t[1])
>>nil
```

So your code is simply returning nil in #t + 1

In practice, it is typical to start a table at 1. However in some applications, such as graphics, it may make more sense to start at 0.